# how to fix memory leakage in c++ array destructor that is reported by valgrind?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, valgrind, destructor

i have tested my app with valgrind and it said a line number that is related to an array destruction.
the original code is :

```
    if ((int)buf.grid -> capacity() >size)
     {
      vector <TPval> *ns= new vector <TPval>;
       {
        *ns= *buf.grid;
         delete buf.grid;
         buf.grid=ns;
        }
       }
```

does anybody know how to fix memory leakage of this section?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Is there a reason you use *pointers* to vectors? Why not use plain *non-pointer* vectors, and just assignment? As for the code you show, perhaps you're looking for the [`std::vector<T>::shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) function?

Comment: You allocate memory for ns and immediately after, overwrite it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: As for a way to solve your problem *with* pointers (which I really don't recommend using), you *are* deleting the pointer somewhere? For every `new` there must be a corresponding `delete`.

Comment: my app is an opensource app and i am trying to test it for memory leakage. this code is related to  the core of application. i think it wanted to decrease memory consumption of buf.grid. but i dont know why it didnt just delete the buf.grid.

Comment: Lastly, if you have C-style casts in your code, it's a sign of you doing something wrong. Perhaps your `size` variables should not be an `int`? Using `size_t` would seem more appropriate, or at least `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: i've used delete for ns but  it causes core dump of the app !

Comment: You should not `delete ns`. You should `delete buf.grid` somewhere. Possibly in a destructor?

Comment: What is `TPval` ?

Answer (score 0):

Other than the issues mentioned in the comments, this code could also leak if an exception is thrown during

```
*ns= *buf.grid;
```

The best way to solve whatever leak is happening would be to replace the whole block with

```
buf.grid->shrink_to_fit();
```

That's a C++11 feature, which might not be available, so you could also try

```
  vector<TPval> ns = *buf.grid;
  std::swap(*buf.grid, ns);
```

inside the condition.